# Does VBA have an equivalent of "Text To" from Visual FoxPro

Tags: vba, visual-foxpro

Visual FoxPro supports syntax such as the following:

```
Text To VariableName TEXTMERGE noshow
select * from.....
EndText
```

This assigns the value of all text between "Text To" and "EndText" to the variable. It eliminates the need for multi line statements separateed by "+ ;"

Does VBA have something similar?

Comment: I'm guessing this syntax would add all the results from the SQL query to the VariableName variable with some kind of delimiter?  If so, you could write your own VB function to do this.  I've done it myself, but I got rid of the code a long time ago, else I'd post it for you.

Comment: @PowerUser, no, it's basically a built in string templating command.  You can have a multiple line block of text with embedded variables without having to do " blah "+var+" blah "+CR_LF+"line two...".

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Short answer: no, nothing similar available.